# Arithmetic sequences and Artin's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

(Sorry if this is a naive question; it is not my area!)

Consider the following strengthening of [Artin's conjecture on primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) (and Dirichlet's theorem) for the case of $n=2$: every arithmetic sequence $a + b \mathbf{Z}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,2)=1$ contains infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$.

As a particular case, are there infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ such that $2$ is primitive mod $p$?

Does this follow either from Artin's conjecture (or its quantitative version) or the GRH (like Artin's conjecture does), or something stronger?

For example, the list [A001122](https://oeis.org/A001122) of $p$ such that $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$ contains, for every odd prime $q \leq 19$ and every $1 \leq b < q$, an entry $p$ such that $p \equiv b \pmod{q}$. This at least a priori makes it possible to imagine that it contains infinitely many such entries (assuming Artin's conjecture, of course!). Also, without the condition $\gcd(a,2)=1$ (i.e. $a$ is odd), then the strengthening fails, of course, as $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$ only if $p \equiv 3,5 \pmod{8}$ (otherwise it is a quadratic residue).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's plausible that there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$
of which $2$ is a primitive residue.  However, this is false for
$p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$, because $2$ is a quadratic residue.
It seems reasonable to guess that this is the only obstruction.

Likewise (*mutatis mutandis*) for other fixed $r$ being a primitive root
modulo infinitely many $p$ in an arithmetic progression:
as long as $r$ satisfies the necessary conditions that $r$ is neither
$-1$ nor a square, the only excluded arithmetic progressions
should be ones in which Quadratic Reciprocity makes $r$ a square $\bmod p$.

**edited to add:** The OP's comment reminds me that Artin's conjecture,
though still open, is known to be a consequence of the GRH
(generalized Riemann hypothesis) for zeta functions of number fields;
Wikipedia helpfully provides a reference (Hooley [1]), and further reminds that
Heath-Brown [2] proved unconditionally that Artin's conjecture holds
for all *primes* $r$ with at most two exceptions.  I'd expect that
these results extend with little further effort to $p$ in arithmetic
progressions in which $r$ is not always a square $\bmod p$;
possibly such extensions are already in the literature.

**References**

[1] Hooley, Christopher (1967). On Artin's conjecture.
*J. reine angew. Math.* **225**, 209--220.
doi:10.1515/crll.1967.225.209

[2] Heath-Brown, D.R. (March 1986):
Artin's Conjecture for Primitive Roots.
*The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics* **37** (1), 27--38.
doi:10.1093/qmath/37.1.27

Comment: Okay, I am glad the intuition seems right —do you think there is a rigorous way to prove this reasonable guess from eg GCH?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Do you mean GRH?

Comment: @TimothyChow Yes, that was a typo, sorry!